# My popup windows wont show even using script

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, popup

i have try everything but still doesn't work. My popup windows only up until header and button but it wont show the body where all the data is in.

[image]

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_data',function(){
        var delete_id  = $(this).attr('id') ; 
        $.ajax ({
            URL : "showbekalan.php",
            type : "post",
            data = {delete_id:delete_id},
            success: function(data){
                $("#deleteInfo").html(data);
                $("#delete").modal('show');
        }
        });
    });
```

```
                              <!-- Modal content-->

<td class="column100 column6" data-column="column6">
  <a href="#delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete_data" id="<?php echo $id ;?>" data-toggle="modal">
    <font size="3">Padam</font>
  </a>
</td>


<div class="modal fade" id="delete" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          <font size="6px"><b>Padam</b></font>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="deleteInfo">
        <form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="deletebekalan.php?bid=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" id="deleteForm">


          <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
            <button class="contact100-form-btn" id="deleteButt">
                                                    <span>
                                                        Padam
                                                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right m-l-8"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also show your html pls.

Comment: i already added it

Comment: That does not make sense, you do not have `#delete` id signup on this modal. Are you sure you posted entire html?

Comment: okayyy, i get it. thank youuu

Comment: If my answer was right make it accepted for future users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_data',function(){
        var delete_id  = $(this).attr('id') ; 
        $.ajax ({
            URL : "showbekalan.php",
            type : "post",
            data = {delete_id:delete_id},
            success: function(data){
                $("#deleteInfo").html(data);
                $("#delete").modal('show');
        }
        });
    });
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_data',function(){
        var delete_id  = $(this).attr('id') ; 
        $.ajax ({
            URL : "showbekalan.php",
            type : "post",
            data = {delete_id:delete_id},
            success: function(data){
                $("#delete").modal('show');
                $("#delete #deleteInfo").html(data); //Assuming that modal window has class modal
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why? ID's must be unique so it really doesn't make sense doing this

Comment: @charlietfl I agree, but he did not present any `HTML` so i can point him up on what class or id he supposed to trigger event.